# Interpretation of Central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that we throw a dice $10'000$ times, and let $S$ be the number of sixes that appear. With the help of the central limit theorem, it can be calculated that

$$P(2'000 \le S \le 10'000) = 0.$$

But doesn't this mean that the probability of throwing a six between $2'000$ and $10'000$ times out of $10'000$ throws is identical with $0$? I don't believe that this is true, because it doesn't seem too unlikely to me to throw a six, say, $3'000$ times overall. Do I interpret the central limit theorem wrongly?

Comment: The probability is not *exactly* zero, but it is extremely close to zero (in fact, it is about $10^{-18}$). Probably the calculator that you used to compute this approximated probability rounded the number down to zero.

Comment: The more you roll your die, the lower the chance you'll get sixes 20% of the times or more, but for any finite number of trials, the probability is not zero.  The probability of your event is $0$ *in the limit* and even an event with probability $0$ is not necessarily impossible.

Comment: S follows binomial distribution, directly computing the probability you mentioned without CLT, I get $P(2\leq S\leq 10)=\sum_{k=2}^{10}\binom{10}{k}(\frac{1}{6})^k(\frac{5}{6})^{n-k} = 0.515483$. Could you specify how you computed the probability?

Comment: @R.Feng ?? The number of sixes in 10'000 throws is binomial $(10,\frac16)$, you think?

Comment: @Did I thought it was ten.